# AngularJS - ng-repeat with a condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of questions to display.

I would like to add a question mark icon next to the question whenever it has a description.

```
    <ul class="list-group" data-toggle="items" ng-repeat="ques in questions">
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" /> {{ques.question}} 
        <div ng-if="{{ques.description}}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="{{ques.description}}"></i>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

So I add all the question and when it has a description I would like to add an icon.

The code above is not working so if you can help !

Thx

Comment: please provide 'questions' array (controller/directive code) and verify your glyphicon-question-sign works by trying it out outside the ng-if condition

Comment: Questions are in my database.
Here is the JSON I receive when I call my service : 
 
{"ID":1,"description":null,"question":"Working during business hours?"}

The glyphicon is actually working everytime, it's always displayed

Comment: would you be using an old version of angularjs by any chance? 1.0.X versions did not have the ng-if directive

Comment: That's it, I'm on v1.0.7
Thank you !

Comment: I upgraded it and now it works ! Thx

Comment: Ok. Otherwise I had posted a workaround below,  just in case...

Comment: Why do you (ng-)repeat the <ul> tag and not the <li> tag? I would expect you want one list with many items and not many lists with one item each.

Comment: Right ! Thx
I'm a novice in AngularJS so sorry ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng-if="ques.description"
```

without the curly brackets, should do it, **with a recent version of angular.js (>1.1)**

For more information, please check the [ng-if official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

---

> However, **if you are using an older version of angular.js**, you cannot use the `ng-if` directive. It would explain why your glyphicon is always displayed, regardless of the `ng-if` condition.

If it is the case, here is a workaround:

```
<div ng-switch="ques.description==null">
   <i ng-switch-when="false" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="{{ques.description}}"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change line:

```
<div ng-if="{{ques.description}}">
```

to:

```
<div ng-if="ques.description">
```

Comment: Still not working.
Actually, I would like to check if the description is not null

Comment: Then you can try: <div ng-if="ques.description != null">

Comment: The icon is always displayed.
btw in my database, the description can be null

Comment: Make sure that `ques.description` is really `null`. (you can use `cosnole.log()`)

Comment: {"ID":1,"description":null,"question":"Working during business hours?"}

That's the JSON when i'm calling my rest service

Comment: Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ddcg83qx/5/ which is updated a bit from @michael-p's fiddle from his answer.

Comment: In this fiddle everything works :) Where `description == null` question mark is hidden. Doesn't it what you want?

Comment: I'm on chrome now and same problem...
I took the $scope.questions array from the fiddle to be sure that some description are null but still not working ....

Comment: Did you open fiddle or your project in chrome? If latter, try open https://jsfiddle.net/ddcg83qx/5/ in chrome just to make sure that we see the same. Here is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/n9RgLR2.png

Comment: I can't open it in chrome, anyway that's what I'm seeing when I'm opening it in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part :

```
    <div ng-if="{{ques.description}}">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="{{ques.description}}"></i>
    </div>
```

with :

```
<span ng-if="ques.description">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="{{ques.description}}"></i>
</span>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/ddcg83qx/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

1st thing remeber `ng-if="expression"` never works with interpolation directive `{{}}` it will need an expression, It would be great if you check length.

And for better binding with title attribute use `ng-attr-title`, it will create title attribute when `{{ques.description}}` get parsed.

```
<div ng-if="ques.description.length > 0">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" ng-attr-title="{{ques.description}}"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working and when I want to display the length of question without description, it displays nothing (not even 0)

Comment: try `$parent.ques.description.length`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the comments below my post.

The probleme was that I was on a 1.0.x version of angularJS which did not have the ng-if directive.

I downloaded a new angular.js and now it works !